# Error accessing Spark with Blaze

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, blaze

Trying to do something fairly straightforward with Blaze and my local Spark instance. Loading a csv file with blaze's into() and then use blaze's by()

```
Python 3.4
Spark 1.4.0
Blaze 0.8.0
```

csv (simple.csv)

```
   id,car
    1,Mustang
    2,Malibu
    3,Mustang
    4,Malibu
    5,Murano
```

code

```
mport blaze as bz
rdd = bz.into(sc,"simple.csv")
simple = bz.Data(rdd)
simple.count()  #gives me 5 so far so good
bz.by(simple.car, count=simple.id.count()) #throws an error
AttributeError: 'InteractiveSymbol' object has no attribute 'car'
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Side note; this works

```
simple_csv = bz.Data("simple.csv")
bz.by(simple_csv.car, count=simple_csv.id.count())
    car     count
0   Malibu  2
1   Murano  1
2   Mustang 2
```

And so does this

```
simple_csv.car.count_values()
    car count
0   Malibu  2
2   Mustang 2
1   Murano  1
```

Gotta be the way I'm "loading" it into Spark, right?

Comment: @PhillipCloud thanks for the comment.  I'm doing it by way of rdd = bz.into(sc,"simple.csv")

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I didn't see that at first. I removed my comment :)

Comment: were you running this in a pyspark shell? I cannot tell how you created the SparkContext

Comment: @pneumatics HI, i did this in a jupyter notebook.  I'm able to do simple pyspark operations with the context.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a Spark DataFrame (formerly `SchemaRDD`) using a `SQLContext` instead of creating a "raw" `RDD` with the `SparkContext`. `RDD`s don't have named columns, which you would need in order for the `by` operation to succeed. This is why the `InteractiveSymbol` did not have a `car` attribute, it was stripped away in the process of creating the `RDD`. Executing this in a Jupyter code cell:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

from odo import odo
simple = odo('simple.csv', sqlContext)
simple.count()
```

would produce a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` object, and execute a program on the Spark driver to count the rows:

```
>>> 5
```

At this point, you should be able to compute the group-by as you were trying to before:

```
import blaze as bz
bz.by(simple.car, count=simple.id.count())
```

BUT. There is a problem with `Blaze`, at least for me, as of today, running Blaze `0.9.0` with both Spark 1.6 and Spark 1.4.1. Likely, this is not the same problem you had in the first place, but it is preventing me from reaching a working solution. I tried dropping Jupyter, and running in a `pyspark` session directly. To do so yourself, you can omit a few of the lines above, since `pyspark` automatically creates `sc` and `sqlContext`:

```
$ pyspark
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.4.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015 18:57:58)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.

from odo import odo
simple = odo('simple.csv', sqlContext)
import blaze as bz
bz.by(simple.car, count=simple.id.count())
```

This produces an error. Even just trying to get an interactive view of `simple` like this also produces an error:

```
simple
```

Anyway, there seems to be some activity in the Blaze project on Github related to upgrading support for Spark 1.6, so hopefully they'll get this stuff fixed at that point.